# user recognizes command but root doesn't

Tags: bash, root, bashrc

I installed arm-linux-g++ and added its directory to PATH and it recognizes the command. But when I try it with sudo it says command not found. I even tried adding its directory to bashrc--root but still nothing changed.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo specifically ignores your PATH variable and uses its own. Compare `echo "$PATH"` with `sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'`. Either put the command in one of the paths sudo trusts, or supply the full path to that particular command.

Comment: you're right it's not in sudo PATH. How can i add it to one of those paths you mentioned?

Comment: @soroosh.strife for instance `sudo cp /path/to/the/command /usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: @geirha Wouldn't `ln -s` be better (as any updates to the command woundn't be reflected if you copy it) , or even fixing the path for sudo?